# Регистрозависимый логин

Tags: php, авторизация

Как сделать регистроНЕзависимые логин пользователя? Дело в том, что при добавлении в базу, логин добавляется оригинальный, например Admin, а если писать в форму входа admin, то уже не совпадение. Хотелось бы, чтобы Admin, admin, AdMiN и т.п. был один и тот же логин.

Comment: Не совсем понял, не могли бы пояснить про "XXX_CI CI - значит case ignore". В общем то, нашел решение проблемы, в БД создать 2 поля, первое оригинальный логин, второе - логин переведенный в нижний регистр. При регистрации пользователя посылать данные в два этих поля, затем, чтобы в профиле выводить оригинальный логин (PrOAdmiN например), а при авторизации сравнивать посылаемый логин со вторым полем записанным в нижнем регистре. Весьма незамысловато, но работает.

Comment: скажу чесно нужно не пытаться слепить снеговика из уже готового, а взять и вставить в нужное место ему морковку в виде одной из ф-й!

ничего вы из написанного ниже не поняли, жаль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtolower($string);` переведёт строку в нижний регистр, `strtoupper($string);` - в верхний.

Comment: Я знаю что есть такие функции, но как их использовать если логин к примеру ProAdmin? При заносе в базу переводить в нижний регистр и при авторизации сравнивать тоже переведенную строку? Но тогда как вывести в профиль оригинальный логин ProAdmin, если в базе только proadmin или PROADMIN.

Comment: Можно также использовать регистронезависимую кодировку, типа _utf8_general_ci_

Comment: Как вариант : логин переводить в нижний регистр и записывать в столбец login_aut, а для вывода в профиль использовать в базе данных столбец login_prf и записывать соответственно в нужном вам регистре, и при необходимости можно изменять логин, меняя значения обеих столбцов.

Comment: Боже мой, нафига хранить 2 логина юзера? Ребят вы чего!

Comment: Поделитесь своими сображения по данной теме, ведь челоеку надо.

Comment: 1. Смысл в 2х одинаковых полях? Бесполезно.

2. Взяли введенный логин от пользователя, при регистрации запишите его так как ввел юзер.

3. когда он логинится проверять логин просто то что он ввел **strtolower($_POST['login'])** и то с чем проверяете в БД тоже **strtolower($row['login'])** все проверили на совпадение и точка. в чем проблема?

Вроде бы все элементарно! И не нужно второго ненужного поля, если так вот захламлять таблицы в БД, то потом можно не просто на грабли наступить, а убиться на поле усеянного этими граблями, т.к. при каждом шаге старо-новые грабли ударят полбу!

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но до меня только сейчас дошло : кодировка utf-8bin в базе данных, тут имеет смысл понятие "регистр символов".

Answer (score 1):

При сравнении логинов запрос к БД составляйте, используя функцию mysql [lower(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lower).

Answer (score 1):

А где у вас хранится этот логин ? Если в базе - то поставьте сопоставление XXX_CI

CI - значит case ignore (регистронезависимый) т.е запросы:

`select * from users where login='admin'
и
select * from users where login='ADMIN'`

идентичны